# Pytest not recognizing added options

Tags: python, pytest

I have a project directory looks like following

```
Projects/
....this_project/
........this_project/
............__init__.py
............code.py
............tests/
................conftest.py
................test_1.py
................test_2.py
```

and I added a command line option (--PALLADIUM_CONFIG) by putting following code into conftest.py

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--PALLADIUM_CONFIG", action="store")

@pytest.fixture
def PALLADIUM_CONFIG(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--PALLADIUM_CONFIG")
```

And what strange is:

if I cd into

```
Projects/this_project/this_project
```

or

```
Projects/this_project/this_project/tests
```

and run

```
py.test --PALLADIUM_CONFIG=***
```

if runs well

but if I locate myself in for example

```
Projects/this_project
```

or

```
Projects
```

then pytest gives me error

```
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --PALLADIUM_CONFIG=***
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's a limitation of pytest itself. Take a look at the [Writing Plugins docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html):

> Note that pytest does not find conftest.py files in deeper nested sub directories at tool startup. It is usually a good idea to keep your conftest.py file in the top level test or project root directory.

One solution is to create an external plugin, or move the option to a `conftest` file nearer the root.

Comment: Is the answer still accurate? I got the same error (in VS Code) with a similar project structure (main project not Python project, wanting to add e2e test suite with pytest). I had a pytest.ini file with `addopts = --my_param some.value`. Changing to `addopts = --my_param="some.value"` fixed it for me. _Will try to reproduce this, then add to pytest issue tracker if relevant - seems like regression of [#1435](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1435)_