# Adding pytest based framework as a dependency

Tags: python, pytest, pythonpath

It's a PyTest (6.2.3) based test framework on Github having the following project structure:

```
auto-test
┣━━Test/src
┃  ┗━━runner.py
┣━━conftest.py
┗━━pytest.ini
```

And it is my application where I want to implement the runner.py from the above **auto-test** module:

```
auto-test-app
┣━━MLTest
┃  ┗━━test-runner.py
┗━━config.ini
```

I'm having difficulty to plug this **auto-test** module to my app **auto-test-app**! I'm just willing to add this **auto-test** module as a dev dependency and automate the tests. Please suggest some best practices to get it done.

**Whatever I've tried so far:**

1. Cloned the **auto-test** somewhere in the system and added it to the environment variable **PYTHONPATH**. And then tried to run this command and got the error as well:

   ```
   user@Mac auto-test-app % pytest MLTest/test-runner.py --config=./config.ini
   ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
   pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --config=./config.ini
     inifile: None
     rootdir: /Users/user/Workspace/POC
   ```

   Apparently, pytest is unable to find out --config, that is inside in auto-test/conftest.py. Pretty much similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522783/py-test-error-unrecognized-arguments).
2. In Eclipse, added **auto-test** directory path to the Properties ⮕ PyDev - PYTHONPATH as External Libraries. And ran through **Py.test runner** configuration in eclipse only. Having the same issue!
3. On top of MLTest/test-runner.py, added sys.path:

   ```
   sys.path.append('/Users/user/Workspace/ML/auto-test')
   ```

Comment: Maybe you are running a different version of `pytest` than the documentation you are searching for. 1) Which version of `pytest` do you have? 2) Are you using any virtual environment?

Comment: pytest 6.2.3, Running in Anaconda environment as well as in Eclipse.

Comment: The problem is, conftest.py needs to locate somehow.. so that the --config could be identified. Can I pass conftest.py path to the pytest command?