# Pytest Addoption configuration not working

Tags: python, selenium, frameworks, pytest

I have built a framework on Pytest to test a web application in multiple environments like QA, UAT, Production etc. Now the url and credentials are different for each server. So I have created different conf.yml file for different server like for production = "conf.yml", for QA "qaconf.yml" etc. Now I have used pytest_addoption in the below way and in the command itself I should mention for which server, I want to execute the test suite

Code

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--conffile",action="store",help="config file")

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def selenium_driver(request):
    config_param = {}
    config_param["conffile"] = request.config.getoption("--conffile")
    # conffile = request.config.getoption("--conffile")
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    conf = TestConfig()
    test = conf.testconf['Test']['AnandRathi']
    driver = conf.WebDriver()
    driver.get(test['Url'])
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield driver
    driver.close()
```

Now while running the test suite I am using the below command but having error

```
pytest -v -s --conffile=conf
```

Error

```
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --conffile=conf
  inifile: None
```

Not sure what I did wrong in this case? Can anyone help? Also providing the yml file below

```
Browser: chrome
Test:
  AnandRathi:
    Url: https://sarathiaapka.com/
    Data:
      Username: "abcdefgh"
      Password: "*****"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem: Which version of pytest, python are you using? Is the code example you gave in the conftest.py file?

Comment: Yes,its the latest version 7 of pytest. I have provided the code of conftest here

Answer (score 1):

I face same issue.

When calling pytest (6.2.5) on the full test suite, it fails:

```
pytest --my-opt foo
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --my-opt
```

but on a single test of the suite, it works:

```
pytest --my-opt foo path/to/a/test.py
```

**EDIT**: this is the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31526934/6508123 (in my example, indeed the `conftest.py` is located in path/to/a.